# Multiple Docusign Account Integration and Billing

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

The purpose of this post is to check if different Docusign accounts can be linked to same application but the billing should be done against a single account.

For example,

Suppose there are three organization OrgA, OrgB and OrgC. OrgA has an agreement with OrgB and OrgC to execute the proposals for them. Docusign account details of OrgB and OrgC are shared with OrgA. Hence while executing and sending an envelope OrgA can use the accounts of OrgB and OrgC. But the billing of the above should be done against OrgA by the Docusign without deducting it from OrgB and OrgC. Is there any way to achieve this in Docusign.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. ***Thank you!***

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ISVs have the option of reselling DocuSign services. In such cases, different customers have limited access to DocuSign and the ISV pays DocuSign for all DocuSign services. See the [OEM licensing docs](https://developers.docusign.com/partner/integration-guide/getting-started-isv/isv-license-oem-implementation/).

Otherwise, no: the sender (creator of the transaction) pays DocuSign. So when Org B sends an envelope, Org B pays DocuSign, even though Org A created the application that was used to send the transaction.